Kubuntu 24.04, how can I change the server for downloading update?
How can I change the server for downloading updates in Kubuntu 24.04?
Update:
Software update setting in Kubuntu:


Software & Updates control panel
-> "Ubuntu Software" tab
--> "Download from" dropdown. Select the server you wish.
On Gnome, it looks like this. On Kubuntu, it will look slightly different:


Hello. I updated the OP. There is no server setting in the software update settings.

Looks like you might be trying to use the wrong control panel. Run software-properties-qt to access the correct control panel.

For Kubuntu I find setting by going into system settings, hardware, driver manager, And then Ubuntu Software and combo box to choose location.

Thanks. So mysterious!
